# Ubuntu Kernel version

Tags: networking, kernel, fedora

I am trying to download network drivers for my Marvell 88E8056: http://www.marvell.com/support/downloads/driverSearchResults.do

There are two versions of the driver:

```
Linux 2.6 Fedora
Linux Kernal 2.4.20 and higher
```

I have run the following command: `uname -r`

which returns:

```
4.4.0-21-generic
```

Does that mean I have: Linux Kernal 2.4.20 and higher?

Comment: I do not think either of these old drivers will work.

Comment: I believe the driver already included in all modern kernels `sky2` supports your device. Installing an older, less developed driver will never compile and, if it did, will make your problems worse! Please start a new question and tell us what's wrong with your ethernet and we'll be glad to help.